# GNOME Shell titlebar missing

Tags: 11.10, gnome

I am using the GNOME Shell interface on Ubuntu 11.10. The black titlebar with Activities, Calender, and the notification icons has disappeared. The Nautilus menu (File, Edit, View, ect.) is at the top instead. If I open any applications, they are missing their titlebar and the buttons, and appear in the top left of the screen. Does anyone know how to fix this? I am using a VGA graphics card, with no driver.

The output of `lspci | grep VEGA` is:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82915G/GV/910GL Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 04)
```

The output of `/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p` is:

```
OpenGL vendor string:   Tungsten Graphics, Inc
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) 915G x86/MMX/SSE2
OpenGL version string:  1.4 Mesa 7.11
Not software rendered:    yes
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes    
Unity 3D supported:       yes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Gnome Shell menu was crashing because of the alternate status menu extension I installed. This bug can be fixed by adding a picture to your profile.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert at all.
But I just had a similar problem while I was tweaking things in compiz-config-settings-manager.
So I opened compiz from the terminal by running: ccsm
And then I clicked on on "Ubuntu Unity Plugin" to activate it.
After reboot, everything was back to normal.

Hope it helps.

Comment: It turns out that it is fixed now. I'm not sure what was wrong, but thank you to everyone who offered help and suggestions!

Comment: Compiz is not related to Gnome Shell. The Compiz setting manager you talked about only works in Unity, because Gnome Shell uses Mutter, got Compiz.